# How to solve $y'=\sin(x+y)+\cos(x-y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This ODE:
$$y'=\sin(x+y)+\cos(x-y)$$ doesn't appear to be separable and substitutions: $x+y=u, x-y=v$ make it tedious. Can some one help me in solving it, please.

Comment: Mmh, I think it is seperable. You can use $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y) + \sin(y)\cos(x)$ and $\cos(x-y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)$. But I do not know, if it helps though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is separable:
$$y'=\sin(x+y)+\cos(x-y) \implies y'=(\sin x+\cos x) (\sin y+\cos y)$$
$$\implies \int \frac{dy}{\sin y + \cos y}=\int (\sin x+\cos x) dx$$
let us write $\sin y$ and $\cos y$ in terms of $\tan(y/2)$ and take $\tan(y/2)=t$, then, we get
$$\int \frac{2 dt}{1-t^2+2t} dt= -\cos x +\sin x +C$$
$$\implies \int \frac{2dt}{2-(t-1)^2}=\sin x-\cos x+C$$
$$\implies \sqrt{2} \tanh^{-1}[\tan (y/2)-1]=\sin x- \cos x+C$$
$$\implies y(x)=2 \tan^{-1}[1+\tanh[\sin(x-\pi/4)+D]] $$

Comment: Thanks for a nice solution